# Detect when <div> is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtouch

I have 4 `<div>`s in my code. I used JavaScript to show and hide them. Now it's getting hard to manage, thus I need to detect if a particular `<div>` is shown or hidden. I'm unsure on how to do this, which way would one code this? JQuery or Jqtouch can be good.
thanks

Comment: Could you post the code or create a JSFiddle?

Comment: How are you hiding the divs? using jQuery? css?

Comment: As in, an event, or just checking at a certain time? Anyway, I'd recommend *making* it easier to manage; it sounds like you want to tack on a part, which will just make it worse.

Comment: Generally speaking, if possible each div should have it's own id. It's not a bad idea to use jQuery to do the showing/hiding.

Comment: Do your div have an id ?

Comment: thanks all, actually I use javascript, but I can also use JQtouch. Every div has his own id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depends on how the divs are hidden exactly but you can probably use

```
if(document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display=="none"){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. First you only use 1 equal sign (assignment) instead of two (comparison) and second this will not check for visibility. Finally, it [doesn't work](http://jsbin.com/obozij/1/edit). unless you use inline style.

Comment: I agree with sachleen. You must correct your code or OP (@user1611253) should mark another answer as accepted. sachleen answer is the best one.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use jQuery to help you, you can use:

```
$( "yourDivSelector" ).is( ":visible" );
```

Without jQuery, you can do:

```
alert( isVisible( "divOne" ) );
alert( isVisible( "divTwo" ) );
alert( isVisible( "divThree" ) );

function isVisible( elementId ) {
    var element = document.getElementById( elementId );
    return window.getComputedStyle( element, null ).display != "none";
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/N3wf6/

More about `window.getComputedStyle` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

Comment: Ops... Sorry, I didn't realized that.

Comment: Shame the question lacked thought, code and eveyrthing else if this was me i would mark this the solution ! +1

Answer (score 3):

This function seems to do what you want. It checks for display none and visibility hidden.

[JavaScript Function Checks For DOM Element Visibility](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/javascript-function-checks-dom)

```
function isVisible(obj)
{
    if (obj == document) return true

    if (!obj) return false
    if (!obj.parentNode) return false
    if (obj.style) {
        if (obj.style.display == 'none') return false
        if (obj.style.visibility == 'hidden') return false
    }

    //Try the computed style in a standard way
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(obj, "")
        if (style.display == 'none') return false
        if (style.visibility == 'hidden') return false
    }

    //Or get the computed style using IE's silly proprietary way
    var style = obj.currentStyle
    if (style) {
        if (style['display'] == 'none') return false
        if (style['visibility'] == 'hidden') return false
    }

    return isVisible(obj.parentNode)
}
```

Example Usage

```
if (isVisible(document.getElementById("myelement"))) {
    // Element is visible.
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/enajif/2/edit)

Answer (score 1):

As im not sure 100% what your doing the hiding /showing...

but if your setting an attribute e.g. display

then..

```
function elementhidden()
{
    1. Get your element
    2. Check the elemnet atrribute status
    3. If its hide value then return true
    4. If its show value then return false

}
```

Provide an example of what your doing so i can make code..

Answer (score 0):

You could use [document.elementFromPoint(x, y)](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint) passing as x and y the position of your div and check it's the good object.

This supposes there is no other element covering the top-left point of your div.

And this may depend of what you mean by "visible" : "entirely visible" ? "at least a little visible" ? What about portions of the viewport that aren't visible due to scroll position ? And if the browser window is partially outside the screen (this could be tricky) ?